# Closing Android App with webview resumes with a runtime error

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

With an app that has Webview on Android. When I close the app (closing the window or Titanium.Android.currentActivity.finish())

I open and close the app the same way again.

The next time I click to open the app I get a Runtime error

Location:ti:/module.js

Message: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'Resources/alloy' in null

Source:return filename in fileIndex;

This happens every time.
Any ideas how to resolve it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to use **Titanium.Android.currentActivity.finish()**. It can have adverse effects.

You should simply use **$.window.close()** method on the web-view window.

Never use that finish() method as activities are automatically handled by Android OS itself when app is put in background & resumes again.

Comment: Thank you. I get the same behaviour when I use $.window.close() - sorry that wasn't clear in my question.

Comment: Can you provide some code snippet & screenshot to reproduce this issue?

Comment: I spoke to Appcelerator and they've confirmed it's an issue. There's a code snippet in the JIRA ticket:
https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-25081